# MongoDB Collections & Data Structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have just started using MongoDB so I apologize if this is an obvious or simple question.

I am trying to store my information using the following data structure:

```
database: {
   Customers: {
       Date_added_1: {
           {customer 1 info},
           {customer 2 info},
           {customer 3 info}
       }
       Date_added_2: {
           {customer 1 info},
           {customer 2 info}
       }
   }
   Employees: {
       Date_hired_1: {
           {employee 1 info},
           {employee 2 info}
       }
       Date_hired_2: {
           {employee 1 info}
       }
   }
}
```

The code I have written to input the information into the database looks like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def addLeadsToDatabase(personCategory, personInformation, date):

    client = MongoClient('localhost', port#)

    db = client.database[personCategory][date]

    db.insert({personInformation})



person_to_add = {'Name':'John Smith', 'Phone':'888-888-8888', 'Email':'example@email.com'}



addLeadsToDatabase('Customers', person_to_add, '06/28/2017')
```

However when navigating through the database it looks like each [personCategory][date] is getting saved as a separate collection. Rather than storing the data first within the personCategory collection, and then within the date sub-collection.

Therefore when I run 'show collections' in the MongoDB shell it outputs:

```
Customers.6/25/2017
Employees.6/25/2017
Customers.6/26/2017
Customers.6/27/2017
Employees.6/27/2017
```

Rather than just:

```
Customers
Employees
```

With the date category stored within each.

Is there a way to store the data the way I have described so it is not making a new collection each time I run the code and just storing data within the appropriate collection(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def addLeadsToDatabase(personCategory, personInformation):

client = MongoClient('localhost', port#)

db = client.database[personCategory]
db.insert({personInformation})

person_to_add = {'Name':'John Smith', 'Phone':'888-888-8888', 'Email':'example@email.com', 'Date': '06/28/2017' } //I would suggest you to use new Date()

addLeadsToDatabase('Customers', person_to_add)
```

Summary:

> Keep it simple. Later on you can filter by date or even aggregate your query by this date.

Comment: Thank you for the input. However the "types" of info Customers & Employees are not the actual data I am working with. I will be gathering 20k different pieces of data per week to which the "Date" is a important categorizing element. I am worried that if store this data together it will slow down querying. Therefore I thought it would be best to separate it out by date so that each collection would be limited to 20k pieces of data and querying within each collection would be faster. Also I am pretty sure that MongoDB limits the MB in one collection.

Comment: Sorry if the types of data I substituted distracted from the 'technical' question because your answer seems to take into account practical implications of the data being stored.

Comment: Well.. you said you got this Customers.6/25/2017, instead of Customer. Thats what made confused. I've never seen sub-collections and if it exists I would be curious to know.

Comment: Okay ya I guess that's my main question as well because it seems to be saving it as a single collection 'Customers.6/25/2017' and I am wondering if it is possible to nest the collections instead. Although I do see your point of how that might somewhat defeat the purpose of a NoSQL database, and make it harder to access certain data...